# GoogleTest & Cmake issue

Tags: cmake, googletest

I'm trying to use gtest for one of my cmake based projects.

This is the cmake that they offer on github, for building gtest at configure time (removed comments to make it shorter):

```
configure_file(CMakeLists.txt.in googletest-download/CMakeLists.txt)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download )
if(result)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake step for googletest failed: ${result}")
endif()
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download )
if(result)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Build step for googletest failed: ${result}")
endif()

set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src
                 ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build
                 EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.11)
  include_directories("${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
endif()

add_executable(example example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example gtest_main)
add_test(NAME example_test COMMAND example)
```

Now, when using this in a very simple project:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── CMakeLists.txt.in
├── build
└── gtest_example.cpp
```

it works as expected. However when adding a test directory with its own CMakeLists.txt and CMakeLists.txt.in and with `add_subdirectory(test)` in the first CMakeLists.txt it doesn't work anymore.

It seems that `execute_process()` fails, since `if(result)` is entered.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this issue on 
[github](https://github.com/google/googletest/pull/1285) which solved my problem. See [file changes](https://github.com/google/googletest/pull/1285/files) for details.

Will accept this answer in case someone has the same problem.